# Data warehouse - OLAP vs OLTP vs Dimentional model vs Relational model

Tags: database, data-modeling, data-warehouse, olap, oltp

I kind of know the difference between **OLAP** and **OLTP**, and the difference between **Dimentional data model** vs **Relational data model**. But how are these 4 terms related with each other? Is OLAP usually "applied" with dimentaional data model design? I'm struggled to link these terms toghether..

Thanks!

Comment: Your best bet is reading `Mastering data warehouse design by Claudia Imhoff`or `OLAP solutions by Erik Thomsen` or `The data warehouse toolkit by Ralph Kimball` or `The Kimball Group Reader - Relentlessly practical tools for data warehousing and business intelligence by Ralph Kimball`. Actually, any book by Ralph Kimball will be useful to you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In a nutshell, and without going into much detail, it boils down to:

- OLAP: analytical queries. Usually related to Kimball's dimensional model, as well as other data warehousing models (Inmon, for example). It usually fetches large volumes of data, which are then aggregated into a report. Response times are long, usually seconds or even minutes. That's ok, as users are usually ok with waiting for a report to finish rendering.
- OLTP: transactional queries. Usually row by row queries used by applications (fetch profile information for current user; insert 1 row into messages table, etc). Low latency, quick response times, but not suitable for large volumes of data. Often used against 3rd normal form databases.